# for free Django VC deployment on AWS, which is best? just EC2.t2 or Beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment, gunicorn

I want to make sure that my instance shuts down whenever the free tier is surpassed, so a literally free site.

For starters, all I could see are alerts, but nothing such as the instance shutting down unless you make some kind of hack that the alert starts a process that shuts down the EC2 which is a bit of a mess.

The deployments on EC2 I have seen are SSH, not VC.

Beanstalk also starts EC2 instances as process is needed which can also spike costs a lot and I am only wanting a free hosted test.

Since Beanstalk is linked to whichever EC2 I suppose you can still link it to a free EC2.t2?

Please avoid recommending other hosting services as AWS is a must for this task.

[beanstalk billing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oAB7.png) seems to charge even on free tier?

Answer (score 0):

EC2.t2

Beanstalk will charge you for the load balancer and the bigger S3